# LZMA SDK Appending files to existing archive C++

Tags: c++, lzma

I've been looking for a solution to append files to an existing archive using the LZMA SDK. I can successfully create a new archive without issues, and understand the idea needed to update an existing archive, but am having trouble understanding how to implement it. Using these two posts on SF, https://sourceforge.net/p/sevenzip/discussion/45798/thread/5d826307/ & https://sourceforge.net/p/sevenzip/discussion/45798/thread/23ec65b4/ it's evident I need to open the existing archive, **then get the list of files in the archive**, append my new files to the list, and create new IOutArchive from my IInArchive.
My issue is the bolded part. I'm unsure how to get the list of items from the existing archive. Any assistance, or preferably code samples as I can't seem to find any, would be greatly appreciated.